# python-pptx access category axis elements "tickLblSkip" & "tickMarkSkip"

Tags: python, python-pptx

I used pptx to create a line chart with a lot of indices.  I would like to tell ppt to label tick marks every 144 indices using the XML element shown here:
http://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/cht-axes.html#related-schema-definitions

Unfortunately I can't figure out how to call that element and can't find any examples to help.  Is anyone able to help?

thanks,
Jerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tick-mark spacing on a value axis (the "Y" axis, generally the vertical axis) is controlled by `ValueAxis.major_unit` and `ValueAxis.minor_unit`:
http://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/chart.html#value-axes

A value axis has both minor and major tick marks. For example, you might have a long tick mark every five units and a short tick-mark every one unit. These can be controlled separately, including causing them not to appear.

In your case, I think you want something like:

```
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_TICK_MARK

value_axis = chart.value_axis
value_axis.major_tick_mark = XL_TICK_MARK.OUTSIDE
value_axis.minor_tick_mark = XL_TICK_MARK.NONE
value_axis.major_unit = 144
```

Note that an XY (Scatter) chart has a value axis for both the X and Y dimensions; therefore tick marks can be controlled separately for each axis.

A category axis has discrete values (category labels), so tick mark units don't apply.

Comment: Thanks for sharing!  Is there a way to also control the category axis label intervals?

Comment: @Jerrance: PowerPoint supports that, but `python-pptx` does not yet. PowerPoint has the category axis attributes "Interval between labels" and "Interval between tick marks" that controls skipping display of label items and individual tick-marks respectively. For example you can display every other one.